# Declare 2d array with unlimited rows and known columns in c++

Tags: arrays

I want to declare a 2D array in c++ like this :

```
char myarray[X][20] ;
```

I don't want to use a high number for X ,i wanna use it as unlimited.

Comment: You can't get this exactly, but you could emulate with dynamic reallocation during run time.

Comment: To do that, you need an unlimited amount of memory.